# Quartz scheduler max thread count property

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have the following situation:

8 tasks scheduled to run with `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount` set to 5.

But in reality I can see that all 8 tasks are running.

How this could be possible?

If I set `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=5` and I submitted 10 tasks for quartz, it is true that only 5 tasks will run in parallel?

What is the meaning of `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount` property?

I have such design:

1. We have some tasks that do some work on entities in db
2. We have special JobRunner that executes one task
3. We scan for tasks to run and schedule task for running in quartz service that is configured with SchedulerFactoryBean with `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount` set to 5.
4. As i understand if quartz service with SchedulerFactoryBean will have 5 tasks running and if we will try to schedule additional task quartz itself should throw an Exception. Is this true?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say that all 8 jobs are running, do you mean that `scheduler. getCurrentlyExecutingJobs()` returns a list of eight jobs? Or that all of them are sending output to System.out? Or what?

Comment: I edited description of the story. So if i schedule 8 tasks for Scheduler and set threadCount=2, doesn it mean that 2 threads will run 8 tasks diving time and changin contexts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's true that QUARTZ's **org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount** is only the max number of concurrent/parallel execution.
That means that if you schedule **X** jobs greater than **threadCount** then **K = X - threadCount** jobs will wait at most a **misFired** milliseconds in some kind of **queue** for **threadCount** jobs to finish.
Thus **Total number of scheduled jobs** (or task) may be **Number of waiting task in queue + Number of running task**. With **Number of running task** less or equal to **threadCount**.