# Scheduling a broadcast message in a sharded Akka Cluster

Tags: java, akka, scheduling, akka-cluster

I'm trying to figure out the best way to trigger all actors of a certain type in a sharded cluster, based on a time schedule (e.g. at 8am, 9am, etc - in cron-like fashion).

My plan was to have a single "timer" actor in the cluster that would send out a broadcast message to other cluster's actors on schedule. However, I'm not sure if this is workable and optimal. [Akka Scheduler](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.31/scheduler.html) doesn't provide cron-like configuration. [akka-quartz-scheduler](https://github.com/enragedginger/akka-quartz-scheduler) doesn't seem to be fitted for Akka cluster.

Is it possible at all to trigger schedule-based actions from inside sharded Akka cluster, perhaps using some other framework's capabilities such as Spring scheduling? Or it's better to deploy a scheduling service outside of sharded Akka cluster, and use it to send periodic triggering events to Akka cluster?

Also, is it possible to broadcast a message to all actors of certain type in sharded Akka cluster?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible at all to trigger schedule-based actions from inside sharded Akka cluster?

In general yes. But it depends on the precision of the scheduled events and the type of the schedule. Let's assume a simple timetable schedule, e.g. everyday at 08:00, with no interest in high precision. It is possible to create an actor with [TimerScheduler](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/actor/typed/javadsl/TimerScheduler.html), lets name this actor `TimerSchedulerActor`. Given a specific time schedule e.g. everyday at 08:00 `TimerSchedulerActor` calculates the next time that the alarm needs to go off  e.g. 01.09.2020 08:00, then `TimerSchedulerActor` compute the duration that it needs to wait from the current time `java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis` to  01.09.2020 08:00. When the TimerScheduler goes off `TimerSchedulerActor`sends the message and calculates the next alarm timestamp for this schedule.

If one `TimerSchedulerActor` is responsible for all messages it should be made sure that there is only `TimerSchedulerActor` running (Singleton actor) as multiple `TimerSchedulerActors` would send multiple messages for each scheduled event. You could also split have different `TimerSchedulerActors` to notify different groups of Actors or to be responsible for different events.

> Or it's better to deploy a scheduling service outside of sharded Akka cluster, and use
> it to send periodic events to Akka cluster?

It could be easier to maintain, easier to deploy and easier debug a scheduling service inside the Akka Cluster. However, the answer depends on the author skills and experience. Someone familiar with a scheduling system outside Akka, (e.g. cron) can perhaps find a faster solution by thinking outside Akka. I would advocate for a solution inside Akka Cluster as it offers more flexibility. For example, if facing a request to change cron (or another external system) from inside the java cluster the complexity would increase.

> Also, is it possible to broadcast a message to all actors of certain type in sharded Akka cluster?

It depends on what the actor type is. [Cluster Receptionist](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actor-discovery.html#cluster-receptionist) can be used to look up specific actors. If you are in control of the message and can add the desired actor type inside the messages and actors a good strategy could be to send the message to all potential actors of this type and let them act on the message based on their type. Actors of the correct type can act on the message and actors of another type could just ignore it.

Comment: Thank you, very insightful. From your explanation a timer inside the cluster seems to be a more capable option, and supposed to work faster comparing with using an external service.

Comment: However, a TimerScheduler is a delayer more than a clock. I don't find an easy way to let the TimerScheduler triggers a task at 8 am each day. Instead, it is used for "trigger this task in 8 seconds" or "run this job every 1 minute from now on until the system shutdowns".

Comment: TimerScheduler is used to schedule events in time using relative time as an input. When absolute (aka wall time) is needed, one can convert relative time to absolute time and use a TimerScheduler. While quartz or quartz-akka have more features I would avoid introducing a  quartz threads and related limitations ( see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986780/quartz-scheduler-max-thread-count-property ). Akka has a different, actor bases concurrency model. Using a singleton akka-quartz-scheduler however as mentioned in another comment seems a good option even if it is not designed for cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You may either:

- Expose an HTTP endpoint that will trigger some tasks, and let airflow or simply a cron job to hit the endpoint
- Use quartz, either akka-quartz-scheduler or raw quartz. I think it fits akka cluster without a problem. What do you think is the blocker? A viable practice may be to run a cluster singleton actor inside which you run schedule-based actions based on quartz.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. From akka-quartz-scheduler's readme: "There aren't currently any plans on having anything to do with the distributed transaction, persistence, clustering or any other nonsense anytime soon." So based on this, I assume it's currently not fitted for the cluster. However, I suppose a singleton actor with akka-quartz-scheduler' in the cluster is worth exploring.